# Open connected subset of $ \mathbb R^2 $is path connected

Tags: general-topology

Is open connected subset of $ \mathbb{R^2} $ is path connected?

Comment: @Timbuc ? The answer is yes.

Comment: Thm: Every locally path-connected connected space is path-connected.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove any path component must be both open and closed.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: The answer is yes.

To prove it, call $U$ the connected, open set, and choose a point $x$ inside. Consider $U'=\{y\in U:\text{ there exists a path from $x$ to $y$}\}$. Prove that $U'$ is open and closed in $U$.

The fact that open balls are path connected will come in handy.